# Azure Graph .Net SDK Users select parameters are case insensitive but Members aren't

Tags: .net, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I've got multiple calls to the Azure Graph API using the .Net SDK.

We get the users and the relevant selections using the following code:

```cs
  var usersResponse = await _graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync(request =>
            {
                request.QueryParameters.Select = new[]
                {
                nameof(User.DisplayName),
                nameof(User.Mail),
                nameof(User.PreferredLanguage)
                };
            }, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

But when querying all members of a group I cannot use this as it results in an empty set of AdditionalData. But using the string values that start with a lowercase it works. So we have to use the following code.

```cs
 var usersResponse = await _graphServiceClient.Groups[azureGroupId].Members.GetAsync(request =>
            {
                request.QueryParameters.Select = new[]
                {
                    "displayName",
                    "mail",
                    "preferredLanguage"
                };
            }, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Why can't I use uppercase `nameof` in the Members call but I can use it in the Users call?

Comment: I also tested it in the Graph Explorer. This shows the same behaviour so it might just be a limitation of the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce and checked the scenario in Microsoft graph explorer and c# code.***

Here users are ***DirectObjects*** to query and so anycase is working out.

[image]

---

[image]

---

But with members of a group if you see , it must first query for directoryObjects  whose Odata is of type Microsoft.graph.user i.e; the users and then the selected parameters
So direct usage of nameOf is not the way to do.

---

> 1. nameof(System.Collections.Generic));  gives output in Generic
> 2. A group can have users, organizational contacts, devices, service principals and other groups as members , so it can’t be same type.

---

Query: `Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/22290xxxxxx-0e5d051cda67/members?$select=DisplayName,Id,GivenName`

[image]

---

With following query , it worked correctly with Uppercase.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/222zz67/members/microsoft.graph.user?$select=DisplayName,Id,GivenName
```

[image]

---

But direct selection of parameters is not giving desired output.
List members is a directory object collection: [group resource type - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[image]

---

[image]

---

For members ,  lower case is working as expected with query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/222xxxcda67/members?$select=displayName,id,givenName`

```
Header : ConsistencyLevel: eventual
```

[image]

---

and
But working perfect with query :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/22xxxf-0xxx1cda67/members/microsoft.graph.user?$select=displayName,id,givenName

Header : ConsistencyLevel: eventual
```

[image]

***You can get the members first which gives a list of users, and there you can use `nameof()` operator .***

This is how i used in my API :

```
 var members = await _graphServiceClient.Groups["222xxxa67"].Members.Request().GetAsync();
        var users = new List<User>();
        users.AddRange(members.CurrentPage.OfType<User>());
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            ViewData["ApiResult"] = nameof(user.DisplayName);
           
        }
```

**and got the out put.**

[image]

**Reference :** [List group members - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Seems that the main takeaway here is that members aren't necessarily Users but DirectoryObjects and apparently have to be queried differently. Thank you for providing that workaround. Seems like a pretty nice solution

Comment: I don't think you need the nameof in your solution because it's already type User.